# Remove all characters in a string after the last ocurrence of a pattern in R

Tags: r, substring, extract

I want to remove all the characters after the last ocurrence of a specific pattern in a string, in R.

For example:

`string = "asdsads dfdsfd>x 442 /<sdasvre (geqwe) ge ge ge regthyty "`

I would like to remove everything after the last ocurrence of the pattern  `"ge"` and end up with:

`"asdsads dfdsfd>x 442 /<sdasvre (geqwe) ge ge ge"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group to capture all strings before the last "ge" (`^(.*ge)`), and replace that whole thing with that capture group (`\\1`).

```
sub('^(.*ge).+$', '\\1', string)
[1] "asdsads dfdsfd>x 442 /<sdasvre (geqwe) ge ge ge"
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer was the most suitable one for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead here:

```
string <- "asdsads dfdsfd>x 442 /<sdasvre (geqwe) ge ge ge regthyty "
output <- sub("\\bge (?!.*\\bge\\b).*", "ge", string, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "asdsads dfdsfd>x 442 /<sdasvre (geqwe) ge ge ge"
```