# Replace only the last occurring pattern of a string

Tags: r, string, gsub

I need to delete the part of a text string that occurs after the last underscore, `_`, of the string, including the underscore. Just to clarify with an example: the initial string is `"surname_name_job"` and I need to change it into `"surname_name"`.

I have tried `gsub("_.*", "", "string")`, but this, of course, deletes after the *first* occurrence of `_`, and I was not able to find the right syntax for deleting from the *last* underscore. Tried also the solution in [Remove all characters in a string after the last ocurrence of a pattern in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72172636/remove-all-characters-in-a-string-after-the-last-ocurrence-of-a-pattern-in-r), but it keeps the last `_`, which I do not want to be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` as follows:

```r
x <- "surname_name_job"
output <- sub("_[^_]*$", "", x)
output

[1] "surname_name"
```

The replacement pattern works by targeting:

- `_` an underscore
- `[^_]*` followed by zero or more non underscores
- `$` end of the string (implying the underscore we targeted was the last one)

Answer (score 1):

if you have a fixed separator (in this case is underscore) you can use the stringr::str_split to remove the string part you dont want.

```
# set the text
text<- "surname_name_job"
# do splitting using underscore as separator
splits<- stringr::str_split(text,'_',simplify=TRUE)
# will remove the last position (as simplify=TRUE splits is a matrix)
splits<- splits[-length(splits)]
# will concatenate the remaining strings using the paste function
newText<- paste(splits,collapse="_")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also  use

```r
sub('^(.*)_.*', '\\1', "surname_name_job")
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/I2V65G) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IoT5GQ/1).

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(.*)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `_` - an underscore
- `.*` -  the rest of the string.